# log4j2: flush logs after worker threads join the main thread

Tags: java, multithreading, log4j2

I am using log4j2 to write logs to console and files for multiple threads. Instead of mixing lines from different threads, I would like to hold the logs for the worker threads, and only flush them when the worker threads join the main thread. How can I do that?

For example, instead of having logs like:

```
Thread 1 started.
Thread 2 started.
Thread 1 working...
Thread 2 working...
Thread 1 working...
Thread 2 working...
Thread 1 finished.
Thread 2 finished.
```

I would like to have:

```
Thread 1 started.
Thread 1 working...
Thread 1 working...
Thread 1 finished.
Thread 2 started.
Thread 2 working...
Thread 2 working...
Thread 2 finished.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Define a `Logger` object per thread.
2. For Logger from (1), disable passing of logs up the hierarchy (set additivity to false)
3. Add a `WriterAppender` to the Logger from (1), passing in a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instance.
4. After joining the threads, get the `OutputStream` defined in (3) and deal with it accordingly

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    BasicConfigurator.configure();
    LoggerRunner[] runners = new LoggerRunner[]{new LoggerRunner("t1"), new LoggerRunner("t2")};
    Thread t1 = new Thread(runners[0]);
    Thread t2 = new Thread(runners[1]);
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t1.join();
    System.out.println("Joined 1");
    t2.join();
    System.out.println("Joined 2");
    System.out.print(new String(runners[0].getLog()));
    System.out.print(new String(runners[1].getLog()));
}

private static class LoggerRunner implements Runnable{

    private final Logger logger;

    private ByteArrayOutputStream logs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    private final String name;
    public LoggerRunner(String name){
        this.name = name;
        logger = Logger.getLogger(name);
        logger.setAdditivity(false);
        logger.addAppender(new WriterAppender(new PatternLayout("%-1r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n"), logs));
    }

    public byte[] getLog(){
        return logs.toByteArray();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        logger.info(name + " started");
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            logger.info(name + " working");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }catch(Exception e){}
        logger.info(name + " finished");
    }
}
```

Comment: In this way I would have to pass the thread-specific logger to wherever I need to write the log. Does log4j2 provide a way to handle this internally?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The above passes the logged data back to the initial calling Thread. You may be able to avoid this by printing the log at the completion of the `run` implementation - to avoid 'collision' of the log of multiple threads you may need to synchronize the calls, perhaps by forcing them to acquire a lock before actually logging out

Comment: I am now using a static logger. But in your answer I will need to create a logger for every thread and pass them around to other classes/methods. Just wonder if there is another way.